# What does axes[0,0] semantics mean in Python?

Tags: python

I'm using **pandas** and **matplotlib** currently and there's a semantic looking like `axes[0,0]`. Since I'm new to Python, I'm wondering what is the difference between it and `axes[0][0]`, which, the latter one, is acknowledged as two-dimensional array indexing.

And what does `axes[0, 0]` literally mean or be implemented?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0, 0` is a tuple. That tuple is passed to the [object `__getitem__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__), and both Pandas and Numpy (which matplotlib relies on) use this to implement multidimensional access.

You can do the same thing in a Python dictionary:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d[0, 0] = 42
>>> d
{(0, 0): 42}
```